# Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-firebase-core:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

Build/Submit details page URL
https://expo.dev/accounts/mensafri/projects/rs-unimus/builds/f3f82e89-2b58-46e1-92a7-89f4393b1087#run-gradlew

Summary
cant build my react native with

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

but can run in my emulator

this is my package.json

```
{
"name": "sim-rs-unimus",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
"@expo-google-fonts/montserrat": "^0.2.3",
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
"@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
"@react-native-community/viewpager": "^5.0.11",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.6.1",
"@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.10",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.16",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
"axios": "^1.6.1",
"date-fns": "^2.30.0",
"expo": "~49.0.15",
"expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
"expo-firebase-core": "^6.0.0",
"expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1",
"expo-font": "~11.4.0",
"expo-image": "~1.3.5",
"expo-permissions": "~14.2.1",
"expo-radio-button": "^1.0.8",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
"firebase": "^10.5.0",
"patch-package": "^8.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
"react-native-pager-view": "6.2.0",
"react-native-popover-view": "^5.1.8",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
"react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
"react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
"react-native-webview": "13.2.2",
"expo-build-properties": "~0.8.3"
},
"overrides": {
"@expo/config-plugins": "~7.2.2",
"@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.2.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
}
```

Managed or bare?
Managed

Environment

```
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
Binaries:
Node: 18.15.0 - D:\NodeJS\node.EXE
npm: 9.8.1 - D:\NodeJS\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526
npmPackages:
expo: ~49.0.15 => 49.0.16
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.72.6 => 0.72.6
Expo Workflow: managed
```

✔ Check Expo config for common issues
✔ Check package.json for common issues
✔ Check dependencies for packages that should not be installed directly
✔ Check for common project setup issues
✔ Check npm/ yarn versions
✔ Check for legacy global CLI installed locally
✔ Check that native modules do not use incompatible support packages
✔ Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK
✔ Check that packages match versions required by installed Expo SDK
✔ Check Expo config (app.json/ app.config.js) schema

Didn't find any issues with the project!

Error output
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1:
Task failed with an exception.
Where:
Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-firebase-core/android/build.gradle' line: 40
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-firebase-core'.
Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-firebase-core:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.